# Using c# to get selected text from other applications

Tags: c#, .net, automation, clipboard, ui-automation

Iam working on a project that need to get selected text from other application anytime user selects some text.

I have used [globalmousekeyhook](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) to monitor when user clicks on an application and i have not problem with that.
My problem is with getting selected text, As i know there are two ways to get selected text from other Applications:
1-Sending copy command([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460943/how-to-get-selected-text-of-any-application-into-a-windows-form-application/21501291#21501291)):
This way works on clipboard and causes some problems with some applications like Adobe reader ([problem](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/441370)),IDM ([clipboard links](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/clipboard_links.html)) And other applications that also work on clipboard.

2-Using UI Automation:
As i have tried and seen that this way cant be used for [get selected text from ANY window (using UI Automation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243944/how-to-get-selected-text-from-any-window-using-ui-automation-c-sharp)
I also edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517694/ui-automation-selected-text?answertab=votes#tab-top) code like bellow but it still not working and slows down my computer

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

AutomationElement ae = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);

AutomationElement npEdit = ae.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Edit"));

TextPattern tp = npEdit.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;

TextPatternRange[] trs;

if (tp.SupportedTextSelection == SupportedTextSelection.None)
{
      return;
}
else
{
      trs = tp.GetSelection();
      label1.Text = trs[0].GetText(-1);
}
```

Isn't there another way to get selected text from other applications?

Or second way can't be used to perform the work?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

An approach might be the use of `Spy++`. Get the handle, extract and parse data you need.