# Is there any way to use onSelect event anywhere?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, desktop-application

I am new at Desktop application. I want to make a simple application that will show a popup with certain value when some text is selected anywhere in the computer like browser/pdf/word document/anywhere. Can anyone show me the approach on how to do it?

Comment: You want to develop desktop, but jQuery, Asp.Net and onSelect event are web. Can you explain?

Comment: The key word you might want to look up is "UI automation".
Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2383854) to a similar question.

Comment: This is not trivial task. Research the words "Mouse Hook", for example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C I hope you are using this for a good thing.